# DataStudio and SQL change time format from numbers to hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, dashboard, looker-studio

I want to change the metric format from float to HH:MM:SS in Datastudio (or SQL).

For Example:

| Float | HH:MM:SS |
| --- | --- |
| 75 | 00:01:15 |
| 90 | 00:01:30 |
| 79.5 | 00:01:20 |

etc........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input seconds fit into 24 hours - so can be presented as a time type  - use below

```
select format_timestamp('%T', timestamp_seconds(cast(seconds as int64))) time
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if input seconds exceed 24 hours - you can use below - which gives you a string representation in format of H*:MM:SS

```
select format('%i:%s',
    div(cast(seconds as int64), 3600),
    format_timestamp('%M:%S', timestamp_seconds(mod(cast(seconds as int64), 3600)))
  ) time
```

with output as

[image]